# I am trying to run the code inside the onMenuItemClick() without pressing the menu button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the code for android activity I want to run, if at all possible without creating a new activity. Need to get rid of the Listener function. I tried to make a new java class but it gave me error on putExtra functions. Also how can I deal with the instance of newConnection inside the Listener constructor.

```
public class NewConnection extends Activity {

  private Bundle result = null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  private class Listener implements OnMenuItemClickListener {

    //used for starting activities 
    private NewConnection newConnection = null;

    public Listener(NewConnection newConnection)
    {
      this.newConnection = newConnection;
    }
```

Trying to run the code below without clicking:

```
    @Override
    public boolean **onMenuItemClick**(MenuItem item) {
      {
        // this will only connect need to package up and sent back
        Intent dataBundle = new Intent();

              String server = ("tsp//:server address");
              String port = ("1823");
              //put data into a bundle to be passed back to ClientConnections
            dataBundle.putExtra(ActivityConstants.server, server);
            dataBundle.putExtra(ActivityConstants.port, port);

              ...

              ...

            //add result bundle to the data being returned to ClientConnections
            dataBundle.putExtras(result);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, dataBundle);
            newConnection.finish();

        }
        return false;

      }
```

This is the code used to call the activity:

```
           createConnection = new Intent();
createConnection.setClassName(
    clientConnections.getApplicationContext(),
    "org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample.NewConnection");

clientConnections.startActivityForResult(createConnection,
    ActivityConstants.connect);
```

Comment: All I can see is a constructor that assigns it's parameter value to a class member. What's the question?

Comment: A constructor which initializes newConnection variable. What is the question actually?

Comment: Please clarify your question as to what you are actually asking

Comment: Sorry I am new with java. The question is if this code is inside NewConnection class, am I creating another instance of NewConnection within the current instance? And what about  this.newConnection = newConnection; what is that doing? Thanks in advance for helping a noob :P

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic constructor within a listener paradigm. It's a core idea within computer science that code should be reusable, and to facilitate this code needs to generally be self contained. This is often done within Java with a listener. It's usually an abstract class or an interface that has a few set functions. The main class that uses the listener is assigned this object or objects, and when it reaches a relevant point will trigger the listener to notify your code of an event.

This allows people to write code that is fully contained and still provide event hooks whereby other user who employ that code can get feedback such as when a menu item is clicked or a new connection is made, and have this dealt with by the person using this code, but without the author of the original class knowing anything about your code. It allows things like menus and connection managers and buttons that have no connection to the code that they trigger, by design. So that any number of these can be made and used.